# Role of Ag2O in Wolff rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry

In Wolff rearrangement, what is the role of $\ce{Ag_{2}O}$ in migration of alkyl/aryl group?

Comment: There is no agreed mechanism for the Wolff. The most convincing thing to say is that it facilitates the loss of dinitrogen.

Comment: Will the reaction happen without the presence of Ag2O ?

Comment: yes, with heat or light. Some rearrangements take place at room temperature